# Best way RecyclerView change itemLayout of all items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want a button to toggle list_item_layout for recyclerView.

I looked on various samples on the so and this https://github.com/gjiazhe/LayoutSwitch (but it's dealing with gridlayoutmanager) I need list layout manager, but different layout files.

But in my case I onScroll load more items and when I change only change adapter parameter variable and notifychange like in that code, I have mix. Some items still use old layout.

So I recreated adapter but I think it is not the best way to solve this.

Here my final code snippet

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_no_image_view) {

        int lastFirstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();


        mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), mPostsList, this);
        mAdapter.setLayoutType(ItemsAdapter.TYPE_LIST);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(lastFirstVisiblePosition);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Is there better way to make it?

UPDATE: Found error, just needed to override @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) and return needed viewtype

And that will make

```
mAdapter.setLayoutType(newType);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

work like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something like:

```
mAdapter.setLayoutType(ItemsAdapter.TYPE_LIST);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Should be all you need. If that's what you were doing and it wasn't working, please post your original code with one adapter.